# Qt signals & slots, Slot is not called on signal emit

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I've been having this problem for few weeks, still didn't found a solution anywhere. I did everything I could to find the problem, everything looks good but for some reason it doesn't work.
I tested the connection, between the loginFailed() signal, and handleLoginFailed() slot, it returned True, printed the object info, it shows the connections. Tried different Qt::connectionTypes, nothing works.

The two objects are defined bellow.

LoginService.h

```
#ifndef LOGINSERVICE_H
#define LOGINSERVICE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
#include "libs/qubeapi/QubeAPI.h"
#include "libs/qubeapi/LoginCommand.h"
#include "libs/qubeapi/APIBridge.h"
#include "libs/mge-users/User.h"
#include "libs/mge-users/permissionfactory.h"
#include "Utils/serverstate.h"
#include "Utils/singleton.h"
#include "Utils/baseservice.h"
class LoginService : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QubeAPI* api;
    APIBridge* bridge;
    LoginCommand* loginCmd;
    QString m_userType;

    QString m_firstName;

    QString m_lastName;

    User *m_user;

public:
    explicit LoginService(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString userType READ userType WRITE setUserType NOTIFY userTypeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString firstName READ firstName WRITE setFirstName NOTIFY firstNameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString lastName READ lastName WRITE setLastName NOTIFY lastNameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(User* user READ user WRITE setUser NOTIFY userChanged)
    const QString &userType() const;
    void setUserType(const QString &newUserType);

    const QString &firstName() const;
    void setFirstName(const QString &newFirstName);

    const QString &lastName() const;
    void setLastName(const QString &newLastName);

    User *user() const;
    void setUser(User *newUser);


signals:
    void success(QString token);
    void loginFailed();
    void userTypeChanged();
    void firstNameChanged();
    void lastNameChanged();
    void staffLogout();
    void userTypeRecived();
    void userChanged();

public slots:
    void requestLogin(QString userName, QString password);
    void loginResponse(QString jsonData);
    void doClose();

    void prepareGetUserType();
    void loadUserType(QString jsonData);




};

#endif // LOGINCONTROLLER_H
```

The function that emits the signal:

```
void LoginService::loginResponse(QString jsonData)
{

    QSignalSpy spy(this,SIGNAL(loginFailed()));
    if(jsonData == "") {
        emit Singleton<ServerState>::GetInstance().offlineServer();
        return;
    }
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData.toUtf8());
    QString token = doc["data"]["tokenAuth"]["token"].toString();

    if(!token.isEmpty()) {
        UserSession::getInstance()->setAuthToken(token);
        emit success(token);
        prepareGetUserType();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Urmeaza eroare";
        QString errorMsg = doc["errors"][0]["message"].toString();
        emit loginFailed();
        qDebug() << spy.count();
    }
}
```

The controller class that has the slot:

```
#ifndef LOGINCONTROLLER_H
#define LOGINCONTROLLER_H


#include <Utils/basecontroller.h>
#include <Utils/enginefactory.h>
#include <Utils/singleton.h>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QThread>
#include <QProperty>
#include <QQmlProperty>
#include "loginservice.h"
#include "draggableviewhelper.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
class LoginController : public BaseController
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QQuickWindow* window;
    QQuickItem* login;
    QQuickItem* userTextField;
    QQuickItem* passwordTextField;
    DraggableViewHelper* draggableViewHelper;
    QQuickItem* mouseArea;
    LoginService* service;
    QPointF lastMousePosition;
public:
    explicit LoginController(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    // BaseController interface

    void initialize();
   // void setService(BaseService* s);
    void setService(LoginService* s);
    void setLastMousePosition(QPointF lastMousePosition);

public slots:
    void handleLoginResponseSuccess(QString loginResponse);
    void handleLoginResponseFailed();
    void handlePositionChanged();
    void handleLogout();
};

#endif // LOGINCONTROLLER_H
```

The initializer methods

```
void LoginController::initialize()
{
    this->engine = Singleton<EngineFactory*>::GetInstance()->createEngine("qrc:/qml/LoginWindow.qml");
    this->window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(this->engine->rootObjects().first());
    // Create a draggable view helper, use window as input
    // Get the view from the engine
    this->draggableViewHelper = new DraggableViewHelper(this->window);
    this->window->setFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    this->login = window->findChild<QQuickItem*>("login");
    this->userTextField = QQmlProperty::read(this->login,"user").value<QQuickItem*>();
    this->passwordTextField = QQmlProperty::read(this->login,"password").value<QQuickItem*>();
    // Set the mouseArea with the mainMouseArea item of the window
    this->mouseArea = window->findChild<QQuickItem*>("mainMouseArea");
    // Connect onClicked from mouse area, to handleMove of this
    QObject::connect(this->mouseArea,SIGNAL(positionMoved()),this,SLOT(handlePositionChanged()));
}


void LoginController::setService(LoginService *s)
{
    this->service = s;//new LoginService;
    connect(this->service,SIGNAL(loginFailed()),this,SLOT(handleLoginResponseFailed()));
    connect(this->service,SIGNAL(success(QString)),this,SLOT(handleLoginResponseSuccess(QString)));
    connect(login,SIGNAL(doLogin(QString,QString)),this->service,SLOT(requestLogin(QString,QString)));
    this->dumpObjectInfo();
    this->service->dumpObjectInfo();
}
```

The slot

```
void LoginController::handleLoginResponseFailed()
{

    qDebug() << "Failed";
    QQmlProperty::write(this->userTextField,"state",QVariant::fromValue(QString{"default-error"}));
    QQmlProperty::write(this->passwordTextField,"state",QVariant::fromValue(QString{"password-error"}));
}
```

This is the main.cpp file, where the objects are created

```
    QApplication app1(argc, argv);
    LoginController* loginCtrl = new LoginController;
    LoginService* loginService = new LoginService;
    QObject::connect(loginService, &LoginService::userTypeRecived,[&](){
        qDebug() << "Failed to login";
    });
    qDebug() << loginService;
    loginCtrl->initialize();
    loginCtrl->setService(loginService);
    //This will trigger the signal
    // loginService->loginResponse("{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Please enter valid credentials\",\"locations\":[{\"line\":1,\"column\":12}],\"path\":[\"tokenAuth\"]}],\"data\":{\"tokenAuth\":null}}");
    return app1.exec();
```

Comment: As an aside, you should really use the new connect syntax: `connect(this->service, &LoginService::loginFailed, this, &LoginController::handleLoginResponseFailed, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);` It helps find connection mistakes at compile-time.

Comment: Why do you want to use `BlockingQueuedConnection`? What is wrong with the default connection?

Comment: I'm curious as to the lifetime of `login`... You instantiate and set it via `this->login = ...` and then reference `login` without the `this->` specification in your connect call. 
1). Is it possible `window->findChild` isn't returning the login object you expect?
2). Are you trying to hit your slot before the event loop has started? The commented out section in main.cpp makes it appear that way. You may need to call app1.exec() before expecting a slot to be hit from a signal.

Comment: If you want to leave that test code in place in main.cpp, maybe try using something like `QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, [this] () { loginService->loginResponse("{ /*rest of your code to force emitting the error*/ });`

Comment: There is no problem with the `login` variable connection. The problem is related to the signals coming from `this->service`